# C# text.Replace preserve case

Tags: c#, text, replace, wiki

I am working on a wiki bot for my communities wiki that uses the DotNetWikiBot Framework; it is to find a word that is commonly a typo (such as "abilty") and replaces them with the correction (such as "ability").

This works as is is coded:

```
p.text = p.text.Replace(@"\b" + typoArray[x, 0] + @"\b", typoArray[x, 1]);
```

However this will replace "Abilty" with "ability" which is of course going to cause issues, but I cannot figure out how to preserve the case of the replaced word (so Abilty becomes Ability) unless the typo replacement is meant to be capitalized, no matter what it is replacing: januray to January

Comment: How to case added characters? Should "aBiLtY" be replaced with "aBiLitY" or "aBiLItY"?

Comment: No, aBiLitY should be replaced by ability and ABiLitY should be replaced by Ability.

Comment: It is simple dictionary words, so there "shouldn't" be stray capitals unless at the start of a sentence or noun.

Comment: Oh I also just realized that the DotNetWikiBot Framework comes with Capitalize and Uncapitalize methods so all I need to be able to find out is if the word I am replacing is capitalized or not.

Comment: @Josh: Your answer doesn't make sense, check my question again... If the replacement word contains more characters, how do you find out which case they should have?

Comment: Is it the first letter of the word? If not it will always be lower case. In the case of the first letter, it only matters what the first letter of the word being replaced is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will do better using Regular Expressions  from the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.

Regex.Replace(str, "[A]", "Z"); or some variant of it. Regular expressions are powerful.

Comment: Thanks, your answer lead me down the right psth to find what I needed.